# Cómo limitar a un máximo?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo limitar `Math.random` a un **máximo número**?

Que me produzca un **número entre 1 y 3**, por ejemplo, y sólo números enteros.

Comment: Has leido la [documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/random) al respecto?

Comment: Si ,pero necesito una explicacion solo me dicen que debo hacer pero no ,por qué

Comment: Eduardo, dices que en la documentacion te dicen **qué** hacer pero no el **porqué**.... sin embargo aceptas una respuesta que hace lo mismo.

Comment: @lois6b pues por que ya entendí gracias a todas las respuetas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente la fórmula sería:

```
 Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) + min
```

En tu caso:

```
 Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('#calcular').click(function(){
    console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="calcular">Calcular</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Según la documentación de [`Math.random()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp):

> Devuelve un número aleatorio entre 0 (incluido) y 1 (excluido).

Así pues, si multiplicas el resultado de `Math.random()` por `3`, obtendrás un número entre 0 (incluido) y 3 (excluido). Para eliminarle los decimales, redondea usando [`Math.round( );`](http://w3schools.bootcss.com/jsref/jsref_round.html), de esta manera también obtendrás el 3 (por el redondeo al alza). Si quieres que sea entre 1 y 3, haz que sea entre 0 y 2 sumando 1.

```js
var numero_aleatorio_entre_0_y_2 = Math.random() * 2;
var numero_redondeado = Math.round(numero_aleatorio_entre_0_y_2);
console.log(numero_aleatorio_entre_0_y_2 + " redondeado " + numero_redondeado + " resultado " + (numero_redondeado + 1));
```

Comment: De hecho si solo hago:  Math.round(Math.random() * 3); , me dá numeros entre 0 y 3

Comment: Efectivamente, de 0 a 3 son cuatro números (0, 1, 2 y 3) mientras que tú pides de 1 a 3 que son tres números (1, 2 y 3). Por ello es más fácil sacar un número de 0 a 2 (0, 1 y 2) sumándole uno.

Comment: el problema con +1 es que puede salirme 4

Comment: Lo que afirmas es matemáticamente imposible. Un número entre 0 y 2 sumando 1, jamás podrá ser 4.

Comment: me refiero al ejemplo que te di yo

Comment: Ah si, en tu ejemplo podría salirte 4, mas nunca 0.

Comment: y como haria para 1 - 3 en mi ejemplo

Comment: Podrías conseguirlo haciendo tal y como se dice [en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/83623/2742).

Comment: ok , pero el 3 sería menos probable?

Comment: Dependerá de la distribución del generador de números aleatorios. Todos los números serán igual de probables si la distribución es uniforme. Una búsqueda en google me indica que no lo es.